# FFMPEG HTTP Stream error, failed: Connection refused

Tags: python, opencv, ffmpeg, video-streaming, http-live-streaming

I tried to stream a video frame from opencv to network using MPEG-Dash, HLS, or RTSP via FFMPEG, but everytime I tried everything, it always throw "Connection Error, Connection Refused" even streaming to 127.0.0.1.

Here the code for testing:

```
import subprocess
import cv2
rtmp_url = "rtmp://127.0.0.1:1935/stream/pupils_trace"

# webcamera is 0, also you can set a video file name instead, for example "/home/user/demo.mp4"
path = 0
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(path)

# gather video info to ffmpeg
fps = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS))
width = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
height = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))

# command and params for ffmpeg
command = ['ffmpeg',
           '-y',
           '-f', 'rawvideo',
           '-vcodec', 'rawvideo',
           '-pix_fmt', 'bgr24',
           '-s', "{}x{}".format(width, height),
           '-r', str(fps),
           '-i', '-',
           '-c:v', 'libx264',
           '-pix_fmt', 'yuv420p',
           '-preset', 'ultrafast',
           '-f', 'flv',
           rtmp_url]

# using subprocess and pipe to fetch frame data
p = subprocess.Popen(command, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)


while cap.isOpened():
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if not ret:
        print("frame read failed")
        break

    # YOUR CODE FOR PROCESSING FRAME HERE

    # write to pipe
    p.stdin.write(frame.tobytes())
```

and below is the log :

```
ffmpeg version 4.2.7-0ubuntu0.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2022 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9 (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.1 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --arch=amd64 --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --disable-filter=resample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librsvg --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opencl --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-nvenc --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      56. 31.100 / 56. 31.100
  libavcodec     58. 54.100 / 58. 54.100
  libavformat    58. 29.100 / 58. 29.100
  libavdevice    58.  8.100 / 58.  8.100
  libavfilter     7. 57.100 /  7. 57.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  5.100 /  5.  5.100
  libswresample   3.  5.100 /  3.  5.100
  libpostproc    55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100
Input #0, rawvideo, from 'pipe:':
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 221184 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (BGR[24] / 0x18524742), bgr24, 1280x720, 221184 kb/s, 10 tbr, 10 tbn, 10 tbc
[tcp @ 0x556bea198680] Connection to tcp://127.0.0.1:1935 failed: Connection refused
[rtmp @ 0x556bea1a2640] Cannot open connection tcp://127.0.0.1:1935
rtmp://127.0.0.1:1935/stream/pupils_trace: Connection refused
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testing.py", line 42, in <module>
    p.stdin.write(frame.tobytes())
```

Here what I tried (All of it always "Connection Refused")

1. Running the code directly
2. Running the code using sudo
3. Run with 'sudo su'
4. Allow the port used in ufw
5. Disable ufw
6. I tried executing command directly in terminal, also throws "connection refused"
7. using 127.0.0.1 or "localhost" or 0.0.0.0 or my local IP, everything throws connection error
8. Tried UDP and TCP

Anyone can help me?
Thanks

Comment: please review [ask] and [mre]. figure out which parts in all of this are __not required__ to reproduce the issue. I'm betting OpenCV is not required. replace OpenCV with plain ffmpeg.

Comment: Execute the listener (the Video Player) before starting FFmpeg sub-process. Example for executing FFplay as shell command: `ffplay -listen 1 -i rtmp://127.0.0.1:1935/stream/pupils_trace`. Example for executing FFplay as Python sub-process (add the line before `p = subprocess.Popen(...)`): `ffplay_process = subprocess.Popen(['ffplay', '-listen', '1', '-i', rtmp_url])`